# redis lua bit overflow

Tags: lua, redis, overflow

I'm working with redis lua and need to perform bitwise logic operations on a field up to 53 bits(the default length of integer part of redis ordered set score)

But it seems I'm out of luck:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> eval 'return bit.lshift(1, 30) ' 0
(integer) 1073741824
127.0.0.1:6379> eval 'return bit.lshift(1, 31) ' 0
(integer) -2147483648
```

It seems bit.* can operate only on 30 bits and then overflows(32 bit signed integer)

I'm using Linux 64 bits and redis is compiled for 64 bits as well.
It looks like a limitation of bit library:

http://bitop.luajit.org/api.html

> Note that all bit operations return signed 32 bit numbers (rationale).
>   And these print as signed decimal numbers by default.

On the other hand...

```
eval 'return math.pow(2, 53) ' 0
(integer) 9007199254740992
```

Any idea how better to overcome this problem?

P.S. someone would say move this logic to client - but I can't. The piece is pretty complicated and needs to work closely to data

Comment: Ok, I found this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7333595/1812225
Purely awful and slow, but looks like redis leaves me without choice :(

Comment: For those interested adding link to redis issue: https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2843

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems bit.* can operate only on 30 bits and then overflows(32 bit signed integer)

Not really. LuaJIT's BitOp works on 32-bit signed integers. That's the reason why 2^31 is a negative number. BitOp documentation explains that the reason to work with signed int32 and not unsigned is because of architecture compatibility issues:

> Defining the result type as an unsigned number would not be
>   cross-platform safe. All bit operations are thus defined to return
>   results in the range of signed 32 bit numbers

http://bitop.luajit.org/semantics.html

This can be troublesome sometimes when comparing the result of a bit operation to a constant. In that case it's necessary to normalize the constant value using `bit.tobit()`. Example:

```
> = bit.lshift(1, 31) == 2147483648
false
> = bit.lshift(1, 31) == bit.tobit(2147483648)
true
```

In any case, LuaJIT's BitOp module is limited to 32-bit integer numbers.

On the other hand, if all the bitwise operations you need are `lshift` and `rshift`, it's possible to code those functions in plain Lua:

```
local function lshift(n, b)
   return n * 2^b
end

local function rshift(n, b)
   return n / 2^b
end
```

Comment: good hint about using simple math for shifts! Allowed me to purge that ugly low/high words implementation and also made code faster ;)