# "interval is empty", Lua math.random isn't working for large numbers?

Tags: random, lua

I didn't know if this is a bug in Lua itself or if I was doing something wrong. I couldn't find anything about it anywhere. I am using Lua for Windows (Lua 5.1.4):

```
>return math.random(0, 1000000000)
1251258
```

This returns a random integer between 0 and 10000000000, as expected. This seems to work for all other values. But if I add a single 0:

```
>return math.random(0, 10000000000)
stdin:1: bad argument #2 to 'random' (interval is empty)
```

Any number higher than that does the same thing.

I tried to figure out exactly how high a number has to be to cause this and found something even weirder:

```
>return math.random(0, 2147483647)
-75617745
```

If the value is 2147483647 then it gives me negative numbers. Any higher than that and it throws an error. Any lower than that and it works fine.

That's `0b1111111111111111111111111111111` in binary, 31 binary digits exactly. I am not sure what that means though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This unexpected behavior (bug?) is due to how `math.random` treats the input arguments passed in Lua 5.1. From [`lmathlib.c`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lmathlib.c.html#math_random):

```c
case 2: {  /* lower and upper limits */
  int l = luaL_checkint(L, 1);
  int u = luaL_checkint(L, 2);
  luaL_argcheck(L, l<=u, 2, "interval is empty");
  lua_pushnumber(L, floor(r*(u-l+1))+l);  /* int between `l' and `u' */
  break;
}
```

As you may know in C, a standard `int` can represent values `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`. Adding `+1` to `2,147,483,647`, like in your use-case, will overflow and *wrap around* the value giving `-2,147,483,648`. The end result is negative since you're multiplying a positive with a negative number.

Furthermore, anything above `2,147,483,647` will fail the `luaL_argcheck` due to overflow wraparound.

There are a few ways to address this problem:

- Upgrade to Lua 5.2. That one has since fixed this issue by treating the input arguments as `lua_Number` instead.
- Switch to LuaJIT which does not have this integer overflow issue.
- Patch the Lua 5.1 source yourself with the fix and recompile.
- Modify your random range so it does not overflow.

Answer (score 4):

If you need a range that is larger than what the random function supports (32 bit signed integers or 2^31 due to sign bit, because math.random is at C level), but smaller than the range of Lua "number" type (based on [What is the maximum value of a number in Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945731/what-is-the-maximum-value-of-a-number-in-lua), 2^52, or maybe even 2^53), you could try generating two random numbers: scale the first to the range desired; add the second to "fill the gap". For example, say you want a range of 0 to 2^36. The largest from math.random is 2^31. So you could do:

```
-- 2^36 = 2^31 * 2^5 so
scale = 2^5
baseRand = scale * math.random(0, 2^31)
-- baseRand is now between 0 and 2^36 but there are gaps of 2^5 in the set 
-- of possible values; fill the gaps with second random number: 
fillGap = math.random(0, 2^5)
randNum = baseRand + fillGap
```

This will work as long as the desired range is less than the Lua interpreter's maximum for Lua numbers, which is a configurable compile time parameter but if you use stock build it is 2^52, a very large number (although not as large as largest long integer, 2^63).

Note also that largest positive N-bit integer is 2^N-1 (not 2^N), but the above technique can be applied to any range, you could have for instance scale = 10^6 then randNum = 10^6 * math.random(0, 10^8) + math.random(0, 10^6).