# Lua error “attempt to perform arithmetic on a string value"

Tags: lua

I have this simple script in Lua:

```
local function addDigits(n)
    n=n..""
    local s1=0

    for i=1,n:len() do
        s1=s1+n:sub(i,i)
    end
    return s1
end
```

If I call it with small values, as

```
addDigits(12345678123456)
```

it performs well. But if I call it with larger values, as

```
addDigits(1234567812345678)
```

I receive “attempt to perform arithmetic on a string value".

I've tried with "toNumber",

```
s1=s1+tonumber(n:sub(i,i))
```

but I recieve "attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value".

I am very new to Lua, so any help will be great! Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945731/what-is-the-maximum-value-of-a-number-in-lua

Comment: Works fine here with Lua 5.3.3

Comment: I use Windows, and the latest version I found is Lua 5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number `12345678123456` becomes `1.2345678123457e+015` when being converted to a string, so you have problem with `s1=s1+"."`, `s1=s1+"e"` and `s1=s1+"+"`.

Comment: I try to use this library here: http://oss.digirati.com.br/luabignum/bn/, but I use the redis-cli, and I cannot use require. So, I just added BigNum.lua in my directory, but still I cannot use the library. Any suggestion?

Comment: "How to install Lua package in redis" is a separate question.  Sorry, I know nothing about redis.