# In Lua error (800000000 + 3000000000 = -2147483648)

Tags: lua

Here is my code. two num plus > 0 but add a variable < 0 !!!

```lua
function addExp(actorExp, val)
    local actorExp = actorExp  -- actorExp  = 800000000
    local val = val -- val = 3000000000
    if actorExp + val  -- Here actorExp > 0 then
        -- actorExp + val > 0 but 
       actorExp = actorExp + val  -- Here actorExp  = -2147483648 ???
    else return end
    updateInfo(actor)
end
```

how can i fix it

Comment: A 32-bit signed integer. It has a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 (inclusive). Maybe this will give you some insight: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5131140/5037430

Comment: What version of Lua is this, in what environment?

Comment: It is inappropriate to change the commenting in a code block because you believe it to be  "wrong", many Lua environments do allow C-like comments as an example garry's mod. As the author did not specify their environment, the commenting at least lends some information that they may not be in a "standard" environment.

Answer (score 0):

This is called an overflow error.

The way computers store data is using binary (`1`s and `0`s), and depending on the size (number of digits) of the binary used to store each number (often 32 'bits') will determine the maximum value. When the maximum value is reached, it will "overflow" back to the start, which in this case is -2147483648 as it is a "signed" (can be negative) number.

Comment: For Lua it's odd though, since Lua usually uses 64-bit floats & ints.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945731/what-is-the-maximum-value-of-a-number-in-lua

Comment: Right, what LMD wrote. It seems this version of Lua is compiled with some non-standard types.